# shell script : write sdterr & sdtout to file

Tags: bash, shell, zsh

I know this has been asked many times, but I can find a suitable answer in my case.

I croned a backup script using **rsync** and would like to see all output, errors or not, from the all script commands. I must write the command *inside* the script itself, and do not want to see output in my shell.
I have been trying with no success. Below part of the script.

```
#!/bin/bash
.....
BKLOG=/mnt/backup_error_$now.txt
# Log everything to log file
# something like
exec 2>&1 | tee $BKLOG 
# OR
exec &> $BKLOG
```

I have been adding at the script beginig all kinds of `exec | tee $BKLOG` with adding `&>, 2>&1`at various part of the command line, but all failed. I either get an empty log file or incomplete. I need to see on log file what **rsync** has done, and the error if script failed before syncing.

Thank you for help. My shell is zsh, so any solution in zsh is welcomed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To redirect all the stdout/stderr to a file place this line on top of your script:

```
BKLOG=/mnt/backup_error_$now.txt
exec &> "$BKLOG"
```